# Attached file issue when sending mail with MVC5

Tags: email, pdf, asp.net-mvc-5, attachment

I want to send campaign mail to customers. There is a PDF file attached.
My contact list is an MS SQL table. I used `foreach` to select each recipient. All emails have an attached file but only the first email has the correct file; others' size is 0.
I checked with debug mode but I couldn't figure it out.

```
public void SendEmail(HttpPostedFileBase Attachedfile)
{
    var smtpHost = GetSmtpInfo("SmtpHost");
    var smtpEmailAccount = GetSmtpInfo("SmtpEmailAccount");
    var smtpPassword = GetSmtpInfo("SmtpPassword");
    int smptPort = Convert.ToInt32(GetSmtpInfo("SmtpPort"));
    string subject = "Test Attached Mail";
    string body = "Test Mail with attachement";

    foreach (var item in db.TblContact)
    {
        using (MailMessage mailMessage = new MailMessage())
        {
            mailMessage.From = new MailAddress(smtpEmailAccount);
            mailMessage.Subject = subject;
            mailMessage.Body = body;
            mailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            mailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(item.Email));
            if (Attachedfile != null)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(Attachedfile.FileName);
                mailMessage.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(Attachedfile.InputStream, fileName));
            }
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
            smtp.Host = smtpHost;
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            System.Net.NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
            NetworkCred.UserName = smtpEmailAccount;
            NetworkCred.Password = smtpPassword;
            smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
            smtp.Port = smptPort;

            try
            {
                smtp.Send(mailMessage);
                ViewBag.success = "Email Sent";
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Error sending mail. Reason :  " + ex.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I need to send each customer a separate email.